# Example of Windows Batch Command to run XUnit Tests in Jenkins?

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, xunit.net

I have just started with Jenkins and configuring Jenkins to run unit tests. 
I am suppose to run Xunit tests using windows batch command.
I wanted to know how to run the XUnit tests by executing a Windows batch command.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to get the package (Chocolatey etc), but I assume NuGet or Paket will work, and you can decide whether to put it in the repo or not.

But the core thing is to get the `xunit.runner.console` NuGet package and then use one of the `xunit.runner.*.exe` files in the `tools/` of that

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple script but should get it done OK.

```
@echo off
cd /d "pathToSolutionDir"
".\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.2.0\tools\xunit.console.exe" "pathToTestingDll"
echo XUnit exited with %errorlevel%
pause
```